# Router stops responding to ARP requests

Tags: router, troubleshooting, arp

I have a Linksys router with OpenWRT installed. The router is connected to another router (router B) which is connected to the internet.

The network mask of router B is 255.255.255.0 and the router has the IP address 192.168.2.1. The Linksys router is connected to router B and has the IP address 192.168.2.2.

In OpenWRT on the Linksys router I created a network in the 192.168.1.1/24 IP range. I have 3 WiFi's running (one in 5Ghz) which all belong to the same network, which also has dhcp enabled.

So a computer connects to a WiFi, gets an IP in the 192.168.1.1/24 range, see's the Linksys router as gateway and can connect to the internet.

This works for a while (hours - days) and then after a while no device can connect the the WiFi anymore.

So I opened Wireshark and looked what happens, my laptop gets an IP assigned (or just takes the last IP it had? I don't know, but the IP is in the 192.168.1.1/24 range) and tries to ARP ping the router.

[image: ARP Pings]

It seems like the router is not responding and therefore my laptop (and any other device) cannot connect to the WiFi.

When I disconnect the router from power and let it restart again all devices can connect to the WiFi and the internet again.

Since always rebooting cannot be a solution - how can I start to debug this? I really want to learn more about networking and want to understand, what is happening here under the hood.

I already tried different search terms but they all just give 'general wifi debugging advice' which didn't help me so far, so I hope to find knowledge here :)

Comment: It might very well be a hardware problem, either the transmit or receive components mysteriously dying – I've had at least two APs with similar symptoms. Check whether your laptop can successfully ARP query _other_ hosts within the same network (wired and wireless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a very weird one:

My WiFi name contained a '&' symbol. After removing that character from the SSID all problems were resolved (including a Raspberry Pi which had a 95% connection failure rate before - now 100% success when connecting).

I'm not sure if this is a problem with OpenWRT, the unix wifi drivers or something else in my network setup. So if someone could reproduce it I'll look where to fill a bug report.